# R: Using indices while looping through list of data frames

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, lapply

For the past couple of days, I have been trying to use indices while looping through a list of data frames to populate the same field in each data frame. But I have been unable to come up with a solution. I'm pretty sure I should be using lapply, but I can't figure out how to reference the row numbers inside a list of data frames to perform the commands.

My data looks like this:

```
           pin        keypin2
01011030030000 01011030030000
01011030030000              0
01011030040000 01011030030000
01011030040000              0
01011040040000 01011040030000
01011040040000 01011040030000
01011040040000 01011040030000
01011040040000              0
01011060040000 01011060010000
01011060040000              0
01011060040000              0
01011060040000              0
```

The goal is to populate "0" values in the keypin2 field with the keypin2 values directly above the "0" values -- on the condition that the pin values match.

I wrote a simple for loop to do accomplish this on a single data frame:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(test3)) {
  if(test3[i,2] == "0") {
    if(test3[i,1]==test3[c(i-1),1]){
      test3[i,2] <- test3[c(i-1),2]
    }
  }
}
```

I start with 2:nrow(test3) because I get a negative index on the first record otherwise, and I know that if the first record has a keypin2 of "0" then I can leave it as "0" because there is no keypin2.

The result is perfect:

```
           pin        keypin2
01011030030000 01011030030000
01011030030000 01011030030000
01011030040000 01011030030000
01011030040000 01011030030000
01011040040000 01011040030000
01011040040000 01011040030000
01011040040000 01011040030000
01011040040000 01011040030000
01011060040000 01011060010000
01011060040000 01011060010000
01011060040000 01011060010000
01011060040000 01011060010000
```

I now want to apply this to a list of data frames, all with the same structure.  I'm convinced I should be able to do this with lapply, but I can't seem to get it right. Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a function embedding your code, and use lapply to the list.

```
   # reproduce data, create list
test3 <- data.frame(
  pin = as.character(
    c(01011030030000,01011030030000,01011030040000,01011030040000,01011040040000,
      01011040040000,01011040040000,01011040040000,01011060040000,01011060040000,
      01011060040000,01011060040000)),
  keypin= as.character(
    c(01011030030000,0,01011030030000,0,01011040030000,01011040030000,
      01011040030000,0,01011060010000,0,0,0)),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)        
my.data <- list(test3, test3)



# define custom function (includes your code)   
    process.df <- function(df) {
      test3 <- df
      for(i in 2:nrow(test3)) {
        if(test3[i,2] == "0") {
          if(test3[i,1]==test3[c(i-1),1]){
            test3[i,2] <- test3[c(i-1),2]
          }
        }
      }
      return(test3)
    }

# execute
    lapply(my.data, process.df)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of performing this without the use of loops is to use the `fill` function from the tidyr package:

```
df<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="pin        keypin2
01011030030000 01011030030000
               01011030030000              0
               01011030040000 01011030030000
               01011030040000              0
               01011040040000 01011040030000
               01011040040000 01011040030000
               01011040040000 01011040030000
               01011040040000              0
               01011060040000 01011060010000
               01011060040000              0
               01011060040000              0
               01011060040000              0",   colClasses=c("character", "character"))

#replace the O with NA
df$keypin2[df$keypin2==0]<-NA

library(tidyr)
#replace the NA with the cell above
fill(df, keypin2, .direction = "down")
```

This is much faster than using a loop, but **it assumes the keypin2[n] is not zero when (pin[n] != pin[n-1])**